# httpurlconnection illegal state exception : already connected

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am trying to post parameters and read the redirected page from inputstream but i don't know anything of this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
    at java.net.URLConnection.setDoOutput(URLConnection.java:900)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setDoOutput(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:455)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

**Code:**

```
try {

        CookieHandler cookieHandler = null;
        CookieManager.setDefault(cookieHandler);


        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("site").openConnection();
        InputStream i = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        StringBuilder stringBuilder =new StringBuilder();


        int c;
        while ((c=i.read())!=-1){
            stringBuilder.append((char)c);
        }

         // for getting the post paramters that is user name and password field
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<input name=\"\\w{22}\" type=\"text\" id=\"\\w{22}\" />");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(stringBuilder.toString());

        String user_name = null;
        while (matcher.find()){

            user_name = matcher.group().split("\"")[1];

        }

        String password = null;
        p= Pattern.compile("<input name=\"\\w{22}\" type=\"password\" id=\"\\w{22}\" />");
        matcher= p.matcher(stringBuilder.toString());
        while (matcher.find()){

            password = matcher.group().split("\"")[1];

        }
        System.out.print(user_name + "  "  + password);



        String urlParameters  = user_name+"=xyz&"+password+"=xyz";
        byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        int    postDataLength = postData.length;

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod(Integer.toString(postDataLength));


        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream()));
        writer.write(urlParameters);
        writer.flush();

        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.getContent();

        while ((c=i.read())!=-1){
            System.out.print((char)c);

        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `urlConnection.setDoInput(true)`, `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true)`, `urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST")`, `urlConnection.setRequestMethod(Integer.toString(postDataLength))` and any other methods that change the query before calling `urlConnection.getInputStream()` and `urlConnection.getOutputStream()` as those methods will actually launch the request so once called it is too late to modify the request that is the reason why you get this `Exception`.

**Response Update**

The main problem that you are actually facing is due to the fact that you want to reuse the `HttpURLConnection` while it is not meant to be reused, that is why you get this exception, you need to create a new `HttpURLConnection` for each HTTP request.

Comment: Actually i need the get parameters at runtime caz the site for which i am using it has it's post paramters has session based encryption . SO, first i need to get that parameter and then  i need to post it....BY the way i did what you said but i m getting another exception that is java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: 60

Comment: "HttpURLConnection is not meant to be reused" I have to remember that, thanks!

Comment: @Broken_Window most Classes are not meant to be reused. Exceptions from this are usually rare and somehow logic: filehandles, databasehandles, threads..